# Unable to build c++ projects in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, compiler-errors

I'm trying to do my end-of-degree project in c++ with Visual Studio and I'm completely stucked for several weeks.
When I try to build any project, VS returns lots of errors and stops the build at the count of 100.
I'm currently trying with a simple Hello world(MSDN example) but it doesn't work.
I installed/uninstalled/reinstalled/repaired VS and its components several times with no success.
I'm a bit desperate with this, I appreciate any kind of help.
Here are some captures of the errors given and the code of the program:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXhUS.jpg

EDIT: I'm also added the output information and what is inside of cmath, which is one of the libraries that causes errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/igSwT.jpg

Thank you for helping, Alex.

Comment: Output window (`Output` tab at the bottom) contains a proper text log of build process. You probably should've posted it instead of screenshots. Also what is inside of *.h files? Main file seems to be fine.

Comment: Create an empty project.  Create a single file with the "hello world" example.  Build it.  Test it.  Resolve any build issues.  Add more files and build again.  Repeat until all the files in the project are incorporated.

Comment: @VTT I edited the post and included screenshots of the output window and cmath file, I don't know if I misunderstood, in that case let me know :) Thank you.

Comment: math.h is standard file installed by VS, not your project file, I was talking about stdafx.h and targetver.h.

Comment: @VTT Oh sorry, I edited the pictures and you can now see what is in these files :) Thank you again for your patience.

Comment: Well, it's not much to say here. Something is probably wrong with our VS install, but that's impossible to guess...

Comment: @VTT Thank you for your time anyway! :D